# FFMPEG Error: Packet too small (67)

Tags: ffmpeg, virtualdub, avi

I am working with win7, FFMPEG Static from May 2016.
I have frequently a bunch of strange avi files to convert by batch and got always the Error:

Packet too small (67)

> Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

I have googled a lot but didn't haven't found a solution. What I have found is that vitualdub is able to fix the AVIs just by "stream copy + save as avi." But I'm having trouble with virtualdub's scripting language.

Is there any solution by using ffmpeg? Or ideas on a virtualdub script to save an avi as avi with stream copy?

[Sample Video](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=796BE2CFECC7A4B6!119&authkey=!AHYyWNXXm1YG0pE&ithint=video%2Cavi)
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a [bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1304).

Comment: :( - Thx. Any Idea how a virtualdub skipt would look like?